# Display users without a group in a template Django

Tags: python, django, usergroups

I am creating an app that allows me to edit users on the frontend. Before doing this I wish to have all the users listed in a page. They are categorized by their group. Users that are in a group show up how they are supposed to. I want to also display users that are not in a group.

This is how I fetch the users in a specific group:
`groupuser = User.objects.filter(groups__name='mygroup')`.

How do I display a user without any group in my template?

I am new to Django and don't know much about this.

Comment: Is your field `groups is `null=True` or what the default value for it if not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the field lookup `__isnull`.

`User.objects.filter(groups__isnull=True)` gives you all the users that do not belong to any group.